# 301 Redirect from /%anyfolder%/ to /Specific folder/ - Apache

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a website that has a bunch of old domain paths. For example.

https://example.com/path1/file.html

https://example.com/path2/file.html

https://example.com/path3/file.html

https://example.com/path4/file.html

And I want to redirect all traffic from any path to a specified path

https://example.com/my-new-path/file.html

I've tried the following in my htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^.*/file.*$ /my-new-path/
```

However, this creates a redirect loop, and I understand why. The question is, I don't know how to get around this.

How can I create a catch all redirect for .* anything, EXCEPT `my-new-path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead regex like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!my-new-path/)[\w-]+/(file\..+)$ /my-new-path/$1
```

`(?!my-new-path/)` is a negative lookahead assertion that matches next pattern using `[\w-]+` except `my-new-path`.

Make sure to use a new browser or clear browser cache to test this rule.

Comment: Sorry got pulled away for something else, I will test this shortly and let you know, I think this will suffice though. Thanks!

Comment: Hello anubhava sir, could you please do let me know if there will be difference if I go for RewriteCond and RewriteRule method and use redirection there? Sorry since I am new to this so asking you here, thank you.

Comment: Sure you can use `mod_rewrite` based rules also.